# How to pass rosparam yaml file on rosrun cmd line

Tags: rosparam, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to pass rosparam yaml file on rosrun cmd line

```
  <node name="ptam" pkg="ptam" type="ptam" clear_params="true" output="screen">
     <remap from="image" to="/camera/image_mono" /> 
     <remap from="pose" to="pose"/>
     <rosparam file="$(find ptam)/PtamFixParams.yaml"/>
  </node>
```

but do

```
 rosrun ptam ptam image:= /camera/image_mono  _rosparam=PtamFixParams.yaml
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273189/how-to-pass-rosparam-yaml-file-on-rosrun-cmd-line/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2017-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, you cannot do this with `rosrun`

You can load parameters from yaml files with the `rosparam load` command: http://wiki.ros.org/rosparam#rosparam_load . You may want to use the namespace argument to load your parameters into the private namespace for your node before you start it.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0